# STM32H723 not entering USB DFU mode

Tags: usb-c, stm32h

Designed a custom STM32H723 board and not able to enter USB DFU mode when holding 'boot0' and releasing 'reset', or when holding 'boot0' and powering the board up.

Note that the MCU code does NOT start up normally if the board is booted with the BOOT0 button held (maybe its entering a different dfu mode?)

I'm able to program the board via swd, reset it via the 'reset' button, Zephyr is running on it, ethernet phy is working, gpios are working, serial shell is working. I haven't tried dfu through other means but plan to in the near future.

One thing I picked up on was the mention of "USB cable detected" and I wonder if, even after being careful, I wired the USB connector incorrectly. Do I need to route USB Vbus to a pin so the CPU knows USB is plugged in, for example? (Today USB Vbus is NOT going to the MCU.)

I've also reviewed https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an5225-usb-typec-power-delivery-using-stm32-mcus-and-mpus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

[image: Bootloader flow chart from AN2606 rev 59]

[image: usb-c schematic snippet]

[image: boot0 and reset buttons]

[image: stm32h723 DP/DM]

[image: MCU connections]

[image: ethernet phy]

[image: external adc]

Comment: It looks like it should work. Maybe the problem is not in these parts of the schematic you show, but in the part you don't show. Post the rest of the circuit.

Comment: @Justme its a huge schematic, what else could it be? It's not the missing usb vbus connection?

Comment: @Justme I also edited the post to reflect that Zephyr is running well on the board, ethernet works, swd programming and debugging, gpio pins, serial shell etc.

Comment: It's not the VBUS. But when you go into bootloader mode, about a dozen or two dozen pins are activated as inputs and outputs for different bootloader interfaces. If any one of them is incorrectly connected, it won't work.

Comment: @Justme AN2606 does say "Configure USB OTG FS Device" but this post on microchip says you can't use otg with type-c, https://microchip.my.site.com/s/article/How-to-do-USB-On-the-go-OTG-on-USB-Type-C. Would you know if there is example wiring for type-c and STM32 usb dfu, I've looked but haven't found any? I wonder if the type-c is causing the issue.

Comment: @Justme and what about the USB OTG ID pin? I'm not mapping that anywhere here either, its just floating.

Comment: Look, as docs say, the bootoader forces the MCU to be in device mode and OTG pin is irrelevant. Your USB connections is also 100% correct. Like I told you, the problem is not in the parts of the schematics you show. It will be in the parts you don't show, or the hardware has a manufacturing error or something else. For example, if pushing the BOOT button while powering up or resetting the MCU makes it not run the normal application, it meas the MCU does run the bootloader, but it gets stuck handling some other interface accidentally instead of selecting USB DFU mode correctly.

Comment: @Justme I get ya on the schematics. It's for a proprietary design so I'm finding it tough to share the whole thing without worry of disclosing too much. Added a few more sections to show the full mcu, and the adc that's on the board. Regarding the BOOT0, it DOES get stuck at boot if BOOT0 is held, the application does not start up. What I don't get is how that's possible. Even with noise on NC pins what are the chances it would always be the proper sequence to go into DFU mode? I haven't tried yet but is possible to figure out which DFU via SWD?

Answer (score 1):

What likely happens is that the bootloader uses so many pins as various bootloader interfaces, that it detects that some other interface must be selected as they take priority before DFU.

The problem is likely not in the unused and not connected pins.

The problem must be in the pins that the bootloader uses, which it configures them as inputs and outputs differently to your main application.

For example, PA3 is used for bootoader UART2 RXD, and you have some analog signal coming in there.

Another problem may be the pins that are configured as outputs during the bootloader mode, you might use a pin as input in your application from some output, but the bootloader will set the pin as output and there are two outputs driving the same line, or the bootloader output drives some important feature on your board to a state it should not be in.

The AN2606 bootloader appnote also says things like UART pins must have pull-ups, and that it is recommended to keep unused bootloader pins in a stable state because leaving them floating might lead to activation of unused interfaces.

That and it does not look like GNDA and GND are connected in the schematics. They likely are but in case they aren't.

Comment: I've got the device showing up in zephyr now but seeing 'PWR not active' errors, the driver is basically stuck starting waiting for PWR to be detected. I tried bridging usb vbus over to PA9 and that doesn't appear to have resolved the issue. Still can't find any guidance from ST on how to wire up type-c to this device.  Could these issues be due to lack of USB ID pin, if the hw is expecting to always be in OTG mode?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan You don't need ST for that, there is only one way to connect any USB device to Type-C connector, you have that 100% correct and you don't need ID pin because STM32 will be in device mode and it will work with Type-B connector also (I think I already told you these BTW). However, please explain how and where GNDA connects to GND? If they are not connected, it will not work, and the chips may be damaged.

Comment: GND and GNDA are tied together (I separated them on the schematic in case I wanted to star ground in the future, and to match nucleo and other schematics). Thoughts on why zephyr would complain about that PWR pin? Same DTS configuration as nucleo (which also doesn't seem to mention mapping for PA9 or the ID pins) and same code targeting the nucleo-h743zi board gets past the PWR status check. I've been combing through data sheets a bit each day to see if I can figure out where I went wrong.